# Virtual keyboard appears on tilt

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a strange situation here. In my android app, I have a layout with various edit text and drop down list. My **problem** is that if I am using virtual keyboard.if for some time I hide the keyboard because I don't want it currently to appear and tilt the device, that is I change from landscape to portrait or vice versa, then again my keyboard appears, although I have minimized it earlier. No matter what i try I had not reached to any solution till now. Since I don't know where exactly my problem is, I am not pasting any code. I can do so if required. Please suggest me something.

**My Try:** I thought problem is focus on first edit box while tilt so tried

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

but focus was there and keyboard reappears. So, I am left with even no guess to solve this. So please help!!!

Any help will appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging so much I found the solution. in the manifest file I used `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateUnchanged"`

This retain the state of keyboard and gives me exactly what I wanted. Apart from that there where few screen where I was getting keyboard like just after login screen, then for that I called hide keyboard method. ***Thanks to all for all help. ***

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand you right, it’s just appears when you change orientation?

Why not use the appropriate listener? Like [OrientationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html)?

Save the status of your keyboard on your activity and read it out on the listener and then set the softkeyboard.

Comment: I got what you are saying. I tried something similar, but I went wrong because i was not saving the state of keyboard. I will try that thanks

Comment: Give it a try, if you have any further question fell free to ask.

Comment: Nothing working right now. No hack no method to find out whether keyboard is shown or hidden.......:-( Really in a mess